# Why local storage does not work with useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, local-storage

I have the following code and it is working fine. `<AddContact />` is a simple component that presents a input form which collects name + email from user - I have attached its code at the end for completeness. The collected `contacts` array is stored in localStorage, and when I refresh the page, they simply get reloaded. all good

```
import './App.css'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function App() {
    const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'contacts'

    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) || [])

    const addNewContact = (newContact) => {
        setContacts([...contacts, newContact])
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.table(contacts)
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts))
    }, [contacts])

    return (
        <AddContact newContact={addNewContact} />
    )
}

export default App
```

my question is that the following revision does not work - every time the page is refreshed, local storage is wiped out. But it really look like it should work - I was following an online tutorial and it was working when the instructor did it.

```
import './App.css'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function App() {
    const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'contacts'

    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]) // changed line

    const addNewContact = (newContact) => {
        setContacts([...contacts, newContact])
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.table(contacts)
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts))
    }, [contacts])

    // added
    useEffect(() => {
        const savedContacts = JSON.parse(
            localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
        )
        if (savedContacts) {
            setContacts(savedContacts)
        }
    }, [])


    return (
        <AddContact newContact={addNewContact} />
    )
}

export default App
```

---

for completeness, here's the code for `<AppContact />`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class AddContact extends Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
    }

    updateState = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    addContact = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (this.state.name === '' || this.state.email === '') {
            return
        }
        this.props.newContact(this.state)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='ui main'>
                <h2>Add Contact</h2>
                <form className='ui form' onSubmit={this.addContact}>
                    <div className='field'>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            name='name'
                            value={this.state.name}
                            placeholder='Name'
                            onChange={this.updateState}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className='field'>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            name='email'
                            value={this.state.email}
                            placeholder='Email'
                            onChange={this.updateState}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button className='ui button blue' type='submit'>
                        Add
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AddContact
```

I would like to understand why the second method does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value you set when calling `addNewContact` does get stored in `localStorage` when the first `useEffect` runs (as expected). The problem is that, when you reload the page, that same `useEffect` is overwriting what's in `localStorage` because the state is reset to an empty array (`[]`). This triggers the `useEffect` with `contacts` equals to `[]`, and stores that in `localStorage`.

---

There are a few ways to handle it, but one way is to check if `contacts` is an empty array before storing its value to `localStorage`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.table(contacts)
    if (contacts.length > 0) {
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts))
    }
}, [contacts])
```

This prevents the initial state of `contacts` to be stored in `localStorage` when the page gets first loaded.

Comment: thank you so much @juliomalves. I now understand the sequence of the event much better. my understanding from your answer, one key point to make is that on a refresh, `setContacts([])` is triggered **before** the `useEffect(() => {}, [])` hook. hence the out-of-sequence update. can you please confirm this or correct me if it's wrong?

Comment: @Steve The first `useEffect` will trigger before the second one, which updates `localStorage` with the initial state value. Which means by the time the second `useEffect` triggers `localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)` will return the empty array too.

Answer (score 1):

In a given render, effect callbacks will run in the order that they're declared. With this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.table(contacts)
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts))
}, [contacts])

// added
useEffect(() => {
    const savedContacts = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
    )
    if (savedContacts) {
        setContacts(savedContacts)
    }
}, [])
```

On mount, the first one runs before the second - you call `localStorage.setItem` before the second one runs `localStorage.getItem` - so by the time the second one runs, storage has been set to the initial value of the `contacts` state, which is the empty array.

To fix it, reverse their order, so that the one that calls `.getItem` runs first.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const savedContacts = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
    )
    if (savedContacts) {
        setContacts(savedContacts)
    }
}, []);
useEffect(() => {
    console.table(contacts)
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts))
}, [contacts]);
```

That said, your first approach of

```
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) || [])
```

looks a lot nicer than an effect hook with an empty dependency array, IMO.

Comment: sorry mate, but swapping the order did not work either. however I did a couple of console log and could confirm that the two got executed in the order of declaration. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are reloading and assigning [] to contacts, simply add if condition for empty contacts.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if (contacts.length > 0) {
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts))
    }  },[contacts]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

I replaced

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.table(contacts)
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts))
    }, [contacts]);
```

with

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (contacts.length > 0) {
      console.table(contacts);
      localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
    }
  }, [contacts]);
```

This worked for me